# Make jenkins auto build one a day but build only when there are source code changed

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, gitlab

I have problem in configure jenkins to auto build and deploy java project. I want to build and deploy once a day. However this build only there are changes during the day. IF there is no changes, I don't want jenkins to auto build and deploy. 
Note: that I used gitlab as source code management. 
Can you help me with this configuration.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you should configure the Git SCM section at the top of the job config page to point to your GitLab repository.

Then you can use the built-in "Poll SCM" build trigger — this will periodically check whether your source code repository has changed — and if it has, a build of this job will be started.

If the repository has not changed since the last build, then no build will be started.

You can configure this trigger — whether using a cron-like syntax, or a shortcut like `@daily` or `@midnight` — so that Jenkins only checks the source repository once a day.

Additionally, you should make sure that the "ignore post-commit hooks" option is enabled.  If you're using webhooks from your Git repository to start Jenkins jobs whenever a commit occurs, this option prevents your once-per-day job from being triggered for every Git commit.

[image]

Comment: Great, I just found that solution too. Anyway, what does option Ignore post-commit hooks used for?? Can you explain a little bit?

Comment: @chetratep It's mentioned already in the answer. If you're using [git webhooks](http://kohsuke.org/2011/12/01/polling-must-die-triggering-jenkins-builds-from-a-git-hook/) to start your Jenkins job, enabling this option will prevent incoming webhooks from triggering a build of this job.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the detail document: "**Jenkins CI integration**"

http://doc.gitlab.com/ee/integration/jenkins.html

---

**Update** to match your comment.

You don't want to trigger the Jenkins build via webhook. It's ok.

You want to check the code change 1 time a day.

Example on Linux, build at 6:00 AM if there's any code change.

- Install

  - https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PostBuildScript+Plugin
  - https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin
- Build Triggers

  - Build periodically: `0 6 * * *`
- Execute shell

Like this

```
SINCE=`curl http://192.168.0.1:8080/job/MyJava/lastStableBuild/buildTimestamp?format=dd-MMM-yyyy`

cd /opt/code/myjava/

git log --pretty="%h - %s" --author=gitster --since=$SINCE --before=$SINCE --no-merges -- t/
```

- Post Build actions

  - Post build task
  - Log text: `commit`
  - Operation: `AND`
  - Script: **Your script to build your Java**
- Jenkins text finder

  - Also search the console output
  - Regular expression: `Could not match`
  - Unstable if found

Comment: I know this configuration. But it look like you dont understand my question. I want to ask if there is way to make jenkins smarter and can identify change in source code in a day and if there is changes then build, but if now make it do nothing. do you understand?